# TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined Jest react testing

Tags: javascript, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I am using jest and enzyme to test the  app components written using material UI library. Then in one of my package I got this error
[Click here to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9YcX.png)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the above problem by following the below steps

1.create a folder and add the below code inside setupFilesAfterEnv.js

```
jest.mock('@material-ui/core/styles/colorManipulator', () => ({

  fade: jest.fn(),

}));
```

2.import the path of the above file in jest.config.js which is in your package folder

```
 setupFilesAfterEnv: [require.resolve('../../test/setupEnzymeAdapter.js'),
<rootDir>../tests/setupFilesAfterEnv.js
```

My issue got fixed with this.